# Why is the other views(table view) doesnt appear in the Customers fxml's border pane when loading inside the main window?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, javafx-11

I'm a very beginner with JavaFX. I'm trying to design some UIs using scene builder.
I want to change the scene into customers ui when user click on the customers button on the home ui. I finally could manage to make it appear. But now it happens this :(

How I want it to be appeared.
[image]

How it appears now.

[image]

Home.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="817.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="home.HomeController">
    <top>
        <Pane prefHeight="167.0" prefWidth="817.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2e0050;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Label layoutX="55.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Techster" textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="50.0" />
                    </font>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="105.0" text="Management System" textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                    </font>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </top>
    <center>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="743.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <GridPane hgap="10.0" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="149.0" prefWidth="491.0" vgap="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="120.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="126.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="126.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="120.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="194.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="194.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnCustomers" contentDisplay="TOP" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClicks" prefHeight="194.0" prefWidth="300.0" stylesheets="@style.css" text="CUSTOMERS">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="70.0" fitWidth="63.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../images/customers.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnContracts" contentDisplay="TOP" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClicks" prefHeight="202.0" prefWidth="309.0" stylesheets="@style.css" text="CONTRACTS" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="70.0" fitWidth="63.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../images/contracts.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnEmployees" contentDisplay="TOP" maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClicks" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" stylesheets="@style.css" text="EMPLOYEES" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="70.0" fitWidth="63.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../images/employee.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

HomeController.java

```
package home;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btnCustomers;

//    @FXML
//    private Button btnContracts;
//
//    @FXML
//    private Button btnEmployees;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    private void  handleButtonClicks(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        if (actionEvent.getSource()==btnCustomers){
            BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Customers.fxml"));
            rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
        }
//
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }


}
```

Customers.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="817.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <Pane prefHeight="167.0" prefWidth="817.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2e0050;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="100.0" layoutY="56.0" text="Customers" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="60.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="817.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <items>
            <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="198.0" prefWidth="817.0">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="683.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Customer" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="817.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView layoutX="6.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="169.0" prefWidth="807.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="28.0">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="ID" />
                        <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="324.0" prefWidth="324.0" text="Name" />
                        <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Contact" />
                        <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="154.0" prefWidth="154.0" text="Date Added" />
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
                  <TextField layoutX="5.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="722.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="90.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
                  <Button layoutX="727.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Button" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: please read the api doc of BorderPane - you are adding the the newly loaded pane incorrectly

Comment: @kleopatra I couldn't find. Can't you correct me here please?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html You shouldn't directly access the child list for a `BorderPane` as there are 5 properties that could be filled with nodes which are the only ones `BorderPane` cares about when doing the layout. Also you're adding a `BorderPane` inside a `BorderPane` which is probably not the desired outcome. (Use `<fx:root>` or replace the scene root instead.) Furthermore I recommend using as little layouts as possible: Use a `GridPane` with a `padding` instead of wrapping it in a `AnchorPane` to get a padding.